# Is there a way to make my add-in run and show in people level not mail item

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

I want to make add-in that show button in contact form to show user email and phone number in task pane , is that available with current web add-in api ?

[image]

And how to make it because i can't found any demo or document for that

Answer (score 1):

No, the current web add-in specification supports only two [item types](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.MailboxEnums#itemtype-string) in Outlook

- Message
- Appointment

Using the web add-in infrastructure for Outlook, it is not possible to show a button in contact form.