# Microsoft Outlook Web Addin Panel on Contact Card?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

When developing a Web Add-in for Outlook is it possible to show the Add-in in a Panel (or otherwise) from an Outlook Contact Card?

The MS documentation does not mention this as a Supported Extension Point or Command. So I believe the answer is no.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#extension-points

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook

Can anyone verify?

Comment: As said, the answer is no, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082192/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-add-in-run-and-show-in-people-level-not-mail-item

Comment: I'm afraid you can't achieve it. Please refer to the link:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been verified and is Not Possible. Only Message and Appointments are supported at this time.

[Is there a way to make my add-in run and show in people level not mail item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082192/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-add-in-run-and-show-in-people-level-not-mail-item)
(Link Provided By SureshGowtham S)